# How to set Keyboard appearance frame

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, textview, scrollview

I am making scrollable and dynamically changing VC and I have a problem: then I touch textView the Keyboard not appearance in my desirable frame. I want that it will be appearance always under my textView and then textView will be change its size - the Keyboard moved to bottom frame textView's size.

How to make that the keyboard will be under the editable string and I can scroll though textView and type where I want ?

Comment: Keyword? or Keyboard?

Comment: So, the issue is that the keyboard covers up your textView. You want that to show it under textView when it is in focus?

Comment: @ GenieWanted, no it is not. I want that keyboard will be under the editable string and I can scroll though textView and type where I want